# three js - How a sphere can shine inside it emitting light to all directions

Tags: three.js

How to make the sun as a sphere shine inside it and radiate light in all directions?

thanks in advance

I have only this rendering at screen the SUN in the center and a box to see how light reflects to it.

```
// create a geometry
  const radius = 2;
  const widthSegments = 100;
  const heightSegments = 96;

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(
    radius,
    widthSegments,
    heightSegments
  );

  const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3, 13, 3);

  //create texture loader
  const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const texture = textureLoader.load("https://i.ibb.co/3srcxqp/Sol.jpg");

  texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  texture.anisotropy = 16;

  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: texture,
    color: "#ffffff",
    specular: "#ffffff",
    transparent: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    alphaTest: 0.5,
    opacity: 1,
    roughness: 1,
  });

  material.alphaMap = texture;
  material.alphaMap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
  material.alphaMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  material.alphaMap.repeat.y = 1;

  var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  const mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);

  scene.add(mesh);
  scene.add(mesh1);

  mesh1.position.set(-10, -10, -10);
  mesh1.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: Maybe this example can help: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bloom#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective

Comment: The [lens flare demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lens#webgl_lensflares) has a cool glowing star lens effect that you can check out.

Comment: On a more basic note, a [`PointLight`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/PointLight) emits light in all directions. To make that light follow your sphere, simply add the light to your sphere: `sphereMesh.add(pointLight);`. In a basic scene without shadows, the light will ignore the sphere's faces. This won't produce the corona effect, blooms, nor flares, but it's a subtle part of tying your sphere to a real light source.